# Crystal reports number rotation and ### in place of number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, int

When I rotate the int number in crystal reports to 90 degree the number displayed as #### I change the width to very large the number displayed. I don't want to change the width so much because I need space for my fields.Any Idea?(it seems I need to change the width equal to length of the number)

Thanks

Comment: you need to alter the width of the field that is the only solution that I see as when `#####` will be displayed on width is not sufficeint for a number to display.

Comment: or decrease font size

Comment: @Siva Thanks for Comment but I have no sufficient horizontal space so I rotate. The vertical width is too long.

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy Thanks for Comment but I have no sufficient horizontal space so I rotate it to 90 degree. The vertical width is too long.

Comment: Try decreasing the font size... Or best way to increase the width by increasing the design space.

Comment: @Siva Thanks so much. But why I rotate the fields to 90 degree (vertical) if I want to increase the horizontal width so much (equal to number length or more.). Don't forget I have many fields and I need horizontal space for them. the vertical width is enough and it is more than the length of the number.

Comment: You can increase the design space by going to page setup... increase as much as possible and increase the width

Comment: @Siva Thanks. I mean the space for the number when I rotate it should be square space(vertical and horizontal length) with the length of the number but i want to take space just in vertical not in horizontal. By the way thanks I don't know how to explain it clearly.

Comment: Please show us some screen shots ;).

Answer (score 1):

I found that the data did not appear to be turning, so the ## was as much of the data as you could see in the space if it were still printing at a 0 turn.  I created a formula to print as text instead of numeric and it began printing correctly.